# Why can't we not open the option menu when the searchbar of SearchBarManager is open?

Tags: android, android-searchmanager, android-optionsmenu

I made ​​an Android application that uses that uses the SearchManager. The problem is that when the search bar is open, the menu button is not working. But in the rest of the aplications, the option button responds very well. Is there a way to run onCreateOptionsMenu when the search bar is open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/search-interface/). It shows how you can use the `onCreateOptionsMenu` with the `SearchManager`.